# How to install redis desktop manager in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, redis

I have redis 3.0.6 installed which gave this output.

````
redis-server
4671:C 23 Jun 05:52:53.351 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
4671:M 23 Jun 05:52:53.352 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.6 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 4671
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'                                               

4671:M 23 Jun 05:52:53.352 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
4671:M 23 Jun 05:52:53.352 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.6
4671:M 23 Jun 05:52:53.352 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
4671:M 23 Jun 05:52:53.352 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
4671:M 23 Jun 05:52:53.352 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
````

http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/#build-from-source
shows we need to clone the project to rdm.shows these steps

```
Download Debian Package from http://redisdesktop.com/download
Install package:  dpkg -i redis-desktop-manager_X.X.X_i386.deb
Run RedisDesktopManager :  /usr/share/redis-desktop-manager/bin/rdm or redis-desktop-manager
```

First we need to clone it.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager.git -b 0.8.0 rdm && cd ./rdm
```

and then those commands

```
cd src/
./configure
source /opt/qt54/bin/qt55-env.sh && make && sudo make install
cd /usr/share/redis-desktop-manager/bin
mv qt.conf qt.backup
```

on typing ./configure I get this output and it says E: Unable to locate package qt54base

```
E: Unable to locate package qt54imageformats E: Unable to locate package qt54tools E: Unable to locate package qt54declarative E: Unable to locate package qt54quickcontrols E: Unable to locate package qt54script E: Unable to locate package qt54quick1
```

as given below.

```
`shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/rdm/src$ ./configure
====================================================================
Build RDM on Ubuntu: 16
====================================================================
====================================================================
Install Qt 542
====================================================================
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                               
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                 
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                 
Ign:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease                                            
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                         
Ign:8 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease                                           
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]                                          
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                           
Get:11 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release [2,940 B]                                                
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                          
Hit:13 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release                                                          
Hit:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                             
Get:16 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release.gpg [455 B]                        
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                      
Ign:16 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release.gpg            
Hit:18 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0/main amd64 Packages  
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Fetched 97.8 kB in 1s (50.5 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key 42F3E95A2C4F08279C4960ADD68FA50FEA312927 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9ECBEC467F0CEB10
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package qt54base
E: Unable to locate package qt54imageformats
E: Unable to locate package qt54tools
E: Unable to locate package qt54declarative
E: Unable to locate package qt54quickcontrols
E: Unable to locate package qt54script
E: Unable to locate package qt54quick1
====================================================================
Check deps
====================================================================
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
automake is already the newest version (1:1.15-4ubuntu1).
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (11.2.0-1ubuntu2).
libtool is already the newest version (2.4.6-0.1).
libssh2-1-dev is already the newest version (1.5.0-2).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-21 linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-21-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
fatal: destination path 'src/third_party/lss' already exists and is not an empty directory.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking a.out.h usability... yes
checking a.out.h presence... yes
checking for a.out.h... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating breakpad.pc
config.status: creating breakpad-client.pc
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/config.h
config.status: src/config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
====================================================================
Run: source /opt/qt54/bin/qt54-env.sh && qmake && make
====================================================================
`
```

but when I type

```
source /opt/qt54/bin/qt55-env.sh && make && sudo make install
```

it gives this result

```
shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/rdm/src$ source /opt/qt54/bin/qt54-env.sh && qmake && make
bash: /opt/qt54/bin/qt54-env.sh: No such file or directory
```

How to evade this and install redis desktop manager.Please provide other alternatives too.

Comment: About alternatives, if you want a fully complete GUI (with monitoring and alerting) you may want to take a look at Redsmin https://redsmin.com

Comment: [Keylord](https://protonail.com/products/keylord) is alternative of RDM too. This is GUI client for Redis. It doesn't require installation to your production servers. Moreover it has already compiled DEB packages for x86/x64 Debian bases distributives.

Comment: I would highly recommend you avoid trying to compile RDM until the author fixes the insecure configure script.  It contains sudo commands to install unknown software to your computer without asking your consent whatsoever.  Just by having run this (and entering your password for sudo prompts) your computer could now be infected with malware!

Unfortunately, Redsmin and Keylord are both proprietary solutions by greedy developers who choose not to give back to the open source community.

RDM is still the best option as it is open source, but the current security concern is very real.

Comment: @hackel It simply doesnt respond in my computer.I have tried several ways for installing t but it simply doesn't help! I don't have any other alternatives, by the way thank you for kindness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem that there's a mistake in their website. You ran this:

```
source /opt/qt54/bin/qt55-env.sh && make && sudo make install
```

While the first commands output asks to run:

```
source /opt/qt54/bin/qt54-env.sh && qmake && make
```

Note the 'q'.

Comment: I don't have the `/opt/qt*` dir. How should I get it? I've treid installing various QT dev packages.

Comment: Actually, I got an answer already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666049/qt-where-to-get-opt-qt59-bin-qt59-env-sh/48667787#48667787