# How to install Redis Desktop Manager on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, redis

I follow the instructions on http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/

I have error:

```
source /opt/qt59/bin/qt59-env.sh && make && sudo make install
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wno-sign-compare -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DRDM_VERSION=\"0.9.999\" -DCORE_LIBRARY -DELPP_QT_LOGGING -DELPP_STL_LOGGING -DELPP_DISABLE_DEFAULT_CRASH_HANDLING -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QUICKWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_CHARTS_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CONCURRENT_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../3rdparty/qredisclient/src -I../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/hiredis -I../../../include -I../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty -I../3rdparty/easyloggingpp/src -I../3rdparty/asyncfuture -I../3rdparty/gbreakpad/src -I/usr/local/bin/rdm/3rdparty/gbreakpad/src/src -I. -Imodules -I/usr/local/bin/rdm/src/../bin/linux/release/ui/ -I/opt/qt59/include -I/opt/qt59/include/QtQuickWidgets -I/opt/qt59/include/QtCharts -I/opt/qt59/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/qt59/include/QtQuick -I/opt/qt59/include/QtGui -I/opt/qt59/include/QtQml -I/opt/qt59/include/QtNetwork -I/opt/qt59/include/QtConcurrent -I/opt/qt59/include/QtCore -I../bin/linux/release/obj -I../../../../include/libdrm -I/opt/qt59/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o ../bin/linux/release/obj/qxtsshclient.o ../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp
../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp: In member function ‘bool QxtSshClient::addKnownHost(const QString&, const QxtSshKey&)’:
../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp:268:14: error: ‘LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_TYPE_ECDSA_256’ was not declared in this scope
         case LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_TYPE_ECDSA_256:
              ^
../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp:269:23: error: ‘LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ECDSA_256’ was not declared in this scope
             typemask|=LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ECDSA_256;
                       ^
../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp:271:14: error: ‘LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_TYPE_ECDSA_384’ was not declared in this scope
         case LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_TYPE_ECDSA_384:
              ^
../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp:272:23: error: ‘LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ECDSA_384’ was not declared in this scope
             typemask|=LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ECDSA_384;
                       ^
../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp:274:14: error: ‘LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_TYPE_ECDSA_521’ was not declared in this scope
         case LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_TYPE_ECDSA_521:
              ^
../3rdparty/qredisclient/3rdparty/qsshclient/qxtsshclient.cpp:275:23: error: ‘LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ECDSA_521’ was not declared in this scope
             typemask|=LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ECDSA_521;
                       ^
Makefile:12390: command for object '../bin/linux/release/obj/qxtsshclient.o' failed
make: *** [../bin/linux/release/obj/qxtsshclient.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you check if you don't have any errors after running "./configure" ?

Comment: I found a tutorial with step by step how to install RDM on Ubuntu 17 but I think it will be helpful for you: https://medium.com/@tadams42/redis-desktop-manager-ubuntu-17-04-1873b5ef812d

Comment: ./configure seems be ok

http://pastebin.pl/view/raw/0b7bb5f9

Comment: Yes, you have right - seems be OK. Try to  install RDM with the older version of Qt as is described in url provided by me in my earlier comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install redis desktop manager in ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790457/how-to-install-redis-desktop-manager-in-ubuntu-16-04)